ASP.NET Core 8 MVC Not Receiving Data from AngularJS HTTP Post Request
I am working on an ASP.NET Core 8 MVC application and facing an issue where the name parameter in my controller is not receiving the value sent from an AngularJS client. Below are the relevant parts of my code
ASP.NET Core 8 MVC controller:

AngularJS code:

I have confirmed through console logs that $scope.newdepartment.Name contains the correct value before making the POST request. However, the name parameter in the AddDepartment method on the server side is always null. What could be causing this issue and how can I fix it?

Try sending $scope.newdepartment instead.

Nop that does not solve the issue

Please avoid posting pictures of code. Post a minimal reproducible example instead.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

In HTTP requests, when sending a POST request, you can observe that the server expects to receive a JSON type.

So you can convert your data into a JSON string. You can do this using the JSON.stringify method, Here is an example you can refer to:
app.controller('Home', function ($scope, $http) {
      $scope.addDepartment = function () {
          $http.post('/Home/AddDepartment', JSON.stringify("ABC")).then(
              function (response) {
                  if (response.data.WasSuccess === true) {
                      alert(response.data.message);
                      window.location.reload();
                  } else {
                      alert(response.data.message);
                  }
              }
          );
      };
  });

Controller:
[HttpPost]
    public IActionResult AddDepartment([FromBody] string name)
    {

        return Ok(new { WasSuccess = true, Message = "Department added successfully." });
    }

When I send data it can be accurately received by the method:


Have Tried this also was not working for me do we need to do anything in startup?

Do you still have the same problem after making the change? You can check if there is any relevant error message in the developer tools. If there is no problem, can you describe your program.cs?

HAve solved the issue created separate VIewModel for everything then it's working for me but with single parameter still not working like you did.Yes may be some issue with Program.cs file
